# is it fine "Have you ever serviced your computer"

Tags: grammar

is it correct to say "Have you ever serviced your computer" please reply

Answer (score 2):

Service is both a noun and a verb.

Have you ever serviced your computer?

There's nothing wrong with the sentence grammatically.  The word "service" is a transitive verb.  You can service your computer if you know how to examine and repair computers.  However, if you cannot do so, then the coorect sentence will be:

Have you ever had your computer serviced?

Comment: As a side note, I avoid "servicing" in regard to people as the object, because of the double entendre with the _"stud service"_ meaning.